# Remove observer from subview

Tags: ios, swift, observers

i have a view which has a dropdownmenu as a subview. Right now i am getting an error, when the view is deallocated. "was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it"

In the views class i am setting the observer:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
    if keyPath == "frame" {
        // Set up DropdownMenu
        self.dropDownBackground.frame.size.height = self.dropDownMenu.frame.maxY
    }   
}
```

And adding it to the subview:

```
dropDownMenu.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: .New, context: nil)
```

So to avoid the error i am trying to do:

```
deinit {
    dropDownMenu.removeObserver(self)
}
```

But the compiler tells me "Cannot invoke 'removeObserver' with an argument list of 'DropDownMenu'"

What am i doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a [look at the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/): the method is called `removeObserver(_ observer: NSObject, forKeyPath keyPath: String)`. So you need to do:

```
dropDownMenu.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
```

Comment: I see! Thank you so much! What i read was that object.removeObserver(anotherObject) would remove all observer connections for the given objects. I guess that was wrong. So thanks again!